# Can't perform segue in other class in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, segue, nsnotificationcenter

I'm new in IOS development. I'm trying to perform a segue of `ViewController1` on other class and I'm using the `NSNotificationCenter` to access the segue method to other class. The segue is working when I'm calling it inside the `ViewController1` but when I'm calling it to other class that give me an error of

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
'NSBundle </Users/dev03/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/9Bsf3724-557D-40F4-A369-F58A31234120/MedsRUs.app> 
(loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-LTT-QY-pu7' and directory 'Main_iPhone.storyboardc
```

In my ViewController1 I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(goToSelectItem:) name:@"performSegueSoldToToSelectItem" object:nil];

}

-(void)goToSelectItem:(NSNotification *)Notif{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"soldTotoSelectItem" sender:self];
 }
```

And this what I did on the other class to call the method goToSelectItem

```
-(void)nextController{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"performSegueSoldToToSelectItem" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use blocks and background thread. The block of code after dispatch_async is executed on a background thread and does not block UI. When the code is completed you can simply perform the segue, this time on main thread.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyNSObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyNSObject *myNSObject = [[MyNSObject alloc] init];

    // do something with myNSObject on a background thread

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        [myNSObject loopFinished];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // perform on main
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
        });
    });
}

@end
```

All UI updates would need to be wrapped with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}, but I assume you are not doing any UI related things in your NSObject class.

Also notice unwind segues are new in iOS6 I believe, so for iOS5 you would need to perform regular segues or present new view controllers in code with push or modally.

Answer (score 1):

You should not access segue of VC1 to 'VC2' from VC2 like that. If you are under UINavigationController, then upon presenting VC2 there will be a Back button on the left side added automatically for your which will bring the user back to VC1.

If you are not under NC or you want to control the next segue fully, you can use unwind segue from VC2 to whichever VC you want. If you want to go back to VC1 without the option provided by NC mentioned above, you simply add this code to VC1:

```
- (IBAction)UnwindFromVC2:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // can add code to execute after the segue is performed
    // note it must be IBAction and the attribute must be UIStoryboardSegue
}
```

and then make a new segue in IB from VC2 to it's Exit (best achieved on the bar under the VC window in IB, just control-drag from the yellow VC icon to the green Exit icon). You will be presented with unwind segue options and you just pick the one your prepared in VC1. You have to set identifier of the segue in IB.

Then you call it from VC2:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindFromVC2" sender:self];
```

**Edit - delegate pattern example:**

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyNSObject.h"

@interface ViewController () <MyCallBack>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyNSObject *myNSObject = [[MyNSObject alloc] init];

    // set myNSObject to be my delegate
    myNSObject.delegate = self;

    // do something with myNSObject
}

- (void)doSegueForMe
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}

@end
```

MyNSObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MyCallBack <NSObject>

- (void)doSegueForMe;

@end

@interface MyNSObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MyCallBack> delegate;

@end
```

MyNSObject.m

```
#import "MyNSObject.h"

@implementation MyNSObject

- (void)loopFinished
{
    [self.delegate doSegueForMe];
}

@end
```

Comment: I need to call the segue operation in a NSObject class not on a Controller

Comment: If the NSObject class is part of your model, then you should not call segues from the model. Controllers are here to manage views and segues between them. If you perform segue to other class, the other class should be a UIViewController or a subclass of it. What kind of class is your NSObject?

Comment: what do you mean what kind of class is my NSObject? I created a class with a type of NSObject and I declared functions of loop inside it the after the loop finish I want to go to another controller that's why I'm calling the segue inside my custom class and not in the controller.

Comment: I meant what does the class do and you explained. In this case your generic class should call back your VC which has created it and this original VC should perform the segue. You can use a notification or better a delegate pattern for the callback.

Comment: Can you show me an example I already use a NSNotificationCenter to pass the segue but when Im calling the postNotification it give me the error from my question.

Comment: why this code do nothing [self.delegate doSegueForMe];

Comment: Double check your code. Important is to add <MyCallBack> on VC interface line, once MyNSObject class exists you need to set your VC to be its delegate in myNSObject.delegate = self; Also put NSLog@("%@", self.delegate); right before [self.delegate doSegueForMe]; to check if the delegate is not nil.

Comment: when I log the delegate it is null. I only follow your codes since I don't have any idea on the delegate. I only added this line of code in my ViewController.h                                  #import "ComputeProductPrice.h"

@interface SoldToController : UIViewController<MyCallBack>

Comment: This is a summary how to construct it: 1. define protocol in NSObject (@protocol-@end), 2. define property in NSObject (@property...i <..> delegate), 3. in NSObject when loop is finished call [self.delegate doWhatever..], 4. in VC you need to import NSObjectclass.h file, 5. set it conforms to its protocol in @interface <..>, 6. implement the callback method (-(void)doWhatever..), 7. once you have a reference to your NSObject class and it is not nil, set its delegate to be self, the VC (myNSObject.delegate = self;) and it must work. Put NSLog in the doSomething and you will see it's working.

Comment: If your delegate is nil as you write double check you set it (myNSObject.delegate = self;) and double check your reference to NSObject class is not nil when you are setting the delegate. Put NSLog(@"%@", myNSObject) right before myNSObject.delegate = self; to see if this is not nil. Another option is to create blank new project based on SingleView template from apple, add MyNSObject class based on NSObject and replace ViewController.m and MyNSObject.h and .m with the above. Then make loopFinished public (add - (void)loopFinished; into .h) and call it from viewDidLoad of VC after //do something

Comment: I did that all and my delegate still null. And what do you mean reference to my NSObject?

Comment: when I log the NSObject before the myNSObject.delegate = self I got this <MyNSObject: 0x8c5a630>

Comment: Just make sure your NSObject based class is not nil when you are setting its delegate. Try these 3 lines: 1. // set myNSObject to be my delegate, 2. NSLog(@"%@", myNSObject); 3. myNSObject.delegate = self;

Comment: I have added the full sample on github. Download the zip, open in Xcode and test it. Then match everything against your project. https://github.com/ddmus/delegateSO

Comment: what does the DelegateSOTest for?

Comment: It's for automated testing, just skip it if you are not doing any.